# How to make shared folder on google drive using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, google-drive-api

I have a function that makes shared files it works perfectly for normal files but when I need to create a public folder it can`t. In [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing?hl=en) they are same operations

```
def GetLinkToFile(file_id,file2):
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + file_id + '/permissions?supportsAllDrives=true'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {'type': 'anyone', 'role': 'reader'}
    res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    link = file2['alternateLink']
    pyperclip.copy(link)
```

This function returns error 400 Invalid request when used with folder and works fine when used with file

Comment: In your situation, when you create a new folder and you run your script to the created new folder including no files and folders, what result will you obtain?

Comment: This function does nothing to the folder with no files or folders.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `This function does nothing to the folder with no files or folders.`. In this case, when your script is run to a new folder including no files and folders, the permission of the folder is not changed and no error occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Permission of folder not changes but error occures

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Permission of folder not changes but error occurs, in this case, when your script is run to a new folder including no files and folders, the permission of the folder is not changed and an error occurs. Is my understanding correct? I apologize for my very poor English skill again.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood `Yes your understanding is correct`. As one more question, in your showing script, `supportsAllDrives=true` is used in the endpoint. Unfortunately, I cannot find whether your drive is the shared drive from your question. How about this?

Comment: How can I see is my drive shared or not?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my very poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How can I see is my drive shared or not?`.

Comment: My drive is not shared

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `My drive is not shared`, if you are using your Google Drive of your account instead of the shared drive, I'm worried about `file_id`. Although from `In your situation, when you create a new folder and you run your script to the created new folder including no files and folders, what result will you obtain?`, you said `Permission of folder not changes but error occures`, if `file_id` is the folder ID of the root folder, an error occurs. Because the root folder cannot be publicly shared. How about this?

Comment: Root folder can be shared through UI of google drive

Comment: The folder is on my google drive and is not in any other folders.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Root folder can be shared through UI of google drive`, I thought that the root folder could not be publicly shared. I apologize for this.

Comment: From `works fine when used with file`, I thought that your script works for the files. Is my understanding correct? Because I think that the request of your script is not correct. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your actual script. How about this?

Comment: Yes, this script works for files, but I need to make a shared folder through the code

Comment: And In theory, it should work

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `And In theory, it should work`, that is about what?

Comment: Its about GetLinkToFile function

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Its about GetLinkToFile function ` and `Yes, this script works for files, but I need to make a shared folder through the code`, I think that unfortunately, when I tested your showing script, an error occurred to both files and folders because that your request body uses an JSON object instead of a sting converted from JSON object. I think that `data=payload` is required to be `data=json.dumps(payload)`. But, you say `Yes, this script works for files`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your actual script. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It works now, it`s so stupid mistake oh

Comment: How can I thank you?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `How can I thank you?`, in this case, when I posted it as an answer, you can accept the answer as the resolved answer. By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Comment: Okay, thank you!!!!!!

Comment: I could notice your modification point by the discussion. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the request for your showing script is required to be modified. So, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### From:

```
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

#### To:

```
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

- In this case, please add `import json`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create)